# The command of 'notify-send' does not work in supervisor

Tags: supervisord, notify-send

My Operating System is `Manjora17.1.12`, the Python version is `3.7.0`, and the Supervisor's version is `3.3.4`.
I have a python script, it just shows a notification. The code is:

```
import os

os.system('notify-send hello')
```

The supervisor config is :

```
[program:test_notify]
directory=/home/zz
command=python -u test_notify.py
stdout_logfile = /home/zz/supervisord.d/log/test_notify.log
stderr_logfile = /home/zz/supervisord.d/log/test_notify.log
```

But when I execute the python script with the supervisor, it doesn't show the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper environment variables need to be set (DISPLAY & DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS). You can do it in many different ways, depending on your needs, like e.g.

**a) per subprocess**

```
import os

os.system('DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send hello')
```

**b) in script globally**

```
import os

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
os.system('notify-send hello')
```

**c) in supervisor config per program**

```
[program:test_notify]
;
; your variables
;
user=john
environment=DISPLAY=":0",DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
```

The above examples have a couple of assumptions (you may want to change these settings accordingly):

- script is run as user john
- UID of user john is 1000
- notification appear on display :0

To run script as root and show notification for regular user, use sudo as described on Arch wiki [Desktop_notifications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications).